# Text adventure game receives AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm working on a text adventure game in Python 3, and what I do not understand is how `def available_actions(self):` is supposed to work.

The file below is my gamedata function where I handle the Location, Items, and World:

```
class Location:

    def __init__(self, brief_description, full_description, available_actions):
    '''Creates a new location.          
    ADD NEW ATTRIBUTES TO THIS CLASS HERE TO STORE DATA FOR EACH LOCATION.

    Data that could be associated with each Location object:
    a position in the world map,
    a brief description,
    a long description,
    a list of available commands/directions to move,
    items that are available in the location,
    and whether or not the location has been visited before.
    Store these as you see fit.

    This is just a suggested starter class for Location.
    You may change/add parameters and the data available for each Location class as you see fit.

    The only thing you must NOT change is the name of this class: Location.
    All locations in your game MUST be represented as an instance of this class.
    '''
        self.get_brief_description = brief_description
        self.get_full_description = full_description
        self.available_actions = available_actions

    def get_brief_description (self):
    '''Return str brief description of location.'''

        return self.brief_description

    def get_full_description (self):
    '''Return str long description of location.'''

        return self.full_description

    def available_actions(self):
    '''
    -- Suggested Method (You may remove/modify/rename this as you like) --
    Return list of the available actions in this location.
    The list of actions should depend on the items available in the location
    and the x,y position of this location on the world map.'''

        return self.available_actions
```

This is the second file below called `adventure.py` where I'm supposed to work on the program of the game itself.

```
import gamedata


if __name__ == "__main__":
    WORLD = World("map.txt", "locations.txt", "items.txt")
    PLAYER = Player(0,0) # set starting location of player; you may change the x, y coordinates here as appropriate

    menu = ["look", "inventory", "score", "quit", "back"]

    while not PLAYER.victory:
        location = WORLD.get_location(PLAYER.x, PLAYER.y)

    # ENTER CODE HERE TO PRINT LOCATION DESCRIPTION
    # depending on whether or not it's been visited before,
    #   print either full description (first time visit) or brief description (every subsequent visit)

        print("What to do? \n")
        print("[menu]")
        for action in location.available_actions():
            print(action)
        choice = input("\nEnter action: ")

        if (choice == "[menu]"):
            print("Menu Options: \n")
            for option in menu:
                print(option)
            choice = input("\nChoose action: ")
```

When I run the file `adventure.py`, I get an error that says

````
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'available_actions'```

This error would be on this line:

    for action in location.available_actions():

Is the reason why I get this error because of the 

    def available_actions(self):
        '''
        -- Suggested Method (You may remove/modify/rename this as you like) --
        Return list of the available actions in this location.
        The list of actions should depend on the items available in the location
        and the x,y position of this location on the world map.'''

            return self.available_actions

In the gamedata function? I'm unsure of how to go about this part of the code and how to fix this error.
````

Comment: The error is in the `World` class. `WORLD.get_location(PLAYER.x, PLAYER.y)` doesn't (always) return a `Location`. It (sometimes) returns `None`.

Comment: @user38034  When i run it i get for action in location.available_actions():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'available_actions'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem should be in the line

```
location = WORLD.get_location(PLAYER.x, PLAYER.y)
```

since in this line the variable  "location" is assigned and the error tells you it is a 'NoneType' Object. Search for the problem in `get_location` of your class `WORLD` and make sure you return the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your World class should be creating Location objects that receive a menu of available options.  Your Location constructor should probably specify that "available_actions" is not empty, since that causes an error later in the code.  And I would imagine in this kind of game, if you were ever in a location with no available actions, the game would just stop.

Answer (score 0):

Your available_action method definition is different from how you use it in adventure.py

You don't pass self into every method, it is implied through instance variables. Passing self will add a variable to the method which, if not addressed in the code, will cause the above error since the signatures do not match. Just remove self from each method in Location.py